# AngularJS and complex JSON returned by django tastypie

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have few resources written on AngularJS that access a Tastypie API. Everything works fine, except for a detail: tastypie always encapsulate the actual result inside a `objects` attribute on a JSON, example:

`/api/v1/reminder/`:

```
{
    meta: {
        limit: 20,
        next: null,
        offset: 0,
        previous: null,
        total_count: 3
    },
    objects: [{
        category: {
            color: "#999999",
            id: 1,
            name: "Groceries",
            resource_uri: "/api/v1/category/1"
        },
        description: "",
        due_date: "2010-10-16",
        id: 1,
        repeat: "weekly",
        resource_uri: "/api/v1/reminder/1",
        value: "-50"
    }, {
        category: {
            color: "#999999",
            id: 1,
            name: "Groceries",
            resource_uri: "/api/v1/category/1"
        },
        description: "",
        due_date: "2010-10-17",
        id: 2,
        repeat: "weekly",
        resource_uri: "/api/v1/reminder/2",
        value: "-50"
    }
}
```

It was wasy to fix using a callback to the `get()` call:

```
Reminder.get().$then(function (result) {
    $scope.reminders  = result.data.objects;
});
```

But I know `result.resource` is an actual `Reminder` instance.

```
.factory('Reminder', ['$resource', function($resource){
    var Reminder = $resource('/api/v1/reminder/:id', {}, {
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: false
        }
    });

    Reminder.prototype.TESTE = function () {console.log('asd');};

    return Reminder;
}])
```

Now I need to implement behavior on my `Reminder` class, and I need every element on my `meta.objects` to be an instance of `Reminder`:

```
Reminder.get().$then(function (result) {
    $scope.reminders  = result.data.objects;

    result.resource.TESTE(); // -> outputs 'asd'

    o = result.data.objects[0];
    o.TESTE // -> undefined, obvisously
    i = new Reminder(o);
    i.TESTE() // -> outputs 'asd'
});
```

So, how to I get angularjs to understand that every object on `objects` is the actual result so it behaves like a list of instances?

The workaround is to creating a new list iterating on the results creating the instances, but it's not optimal...

Suggestions?

## Solution by @rtcherry:

As suggested by rtcherry, I used [restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular)

Configuring the reading of request data:

```
.config(['RestangularProvider', function(RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl("/api/v1");

    RestangularProvider.setResponseExtractor(function(response, operation, what, url) {
        var newResponse;
        if (operation === "getList") {
            newResponse = response.objects;
            newResponse.metadata = response.meta;
        } else {
            newResponse = response.data;
        }
        return newResponse;
    });
}])
```

Loading the reminders:

```
function RemindersCtrl ($scope, $rootScope, Reminder) {
    $scope.reminders = Reminder.getList();
}
```

Adding my custom method to `Reminder` (not as clean as ngResource, but doable):

```
.factory('Reminder', ['Restangular', '$filter', function(Restangular, $filter){
    var Reminder = Restangular.all('reminder');

    var remainingDays = function () {
        //do stuff
    };

    // adding custom behavior
    Restangular.addElementTransformer('reminder', false, function (reminder) {
        reminder.remainingDays = remainingDays;
        return reminder;
    });

    return Reminder;
}])
```

## Solution by @moderndegree:

I used pure `ngResource`:

```
var tastypieDataTransformer = function ($http) {
    return $http.defaults.transformResponse.concat([
        function (data, headersGetter) {
            var result = data.objects;
            result.meta = data.meta;
            return result;
        }
    ])
};

...

.factory('Reminder', ['$resource', '$http', function($resource, $http){
    var Reminder = $resource('/api/v1/reminder/:id', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,
            transformResponse: tastypieDataTransformer($http)
        }
    });

    Reminder.prototype.remainingDays = function () {
        // doing stuff
    };

    return Reminder;
}])
```

My controller:

```
Transaction.query(filter).$then(function (result) {
    $scope.days = [];
    var transactions = result.resource;
    resource[0].remainingDays(); // it works

});
```

Comment: You may want to try something like [restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular).

Comment: whoa, seems good.. i will look into it

Comment: done. it's not as easy as adding a method to a angular resource, but can be done.. 
but restangular pays off on it's many useful features.
do you want to make an answer out of your comment so I can mark it?

Comment: Hey, I'm the creator of Restangular. If you have to choose, which one do you want better ngResource or Restangular for all your usage? And why? Thanks for the information to make Restangular better :)

Comment: Is the solution by @moderndegree working in 1.2.12? I am trying to return list of object and include a meta element to presever the total_pages (to avoid yet another request just for that). It seems even though I transformResponse exacactly like in the example, the meta is not available later on in the returned object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wanted to avoid using an additional library, you should be able to do the following:

```
$resource('/api/v1/reminder/', {}, {
    query: {
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: true,
        transformResponse: $http.defaults.transformResponse.concat([
            function (data, headersGetter) {
                return data.objects;
            }
        ])
    }
});
```

This will append your transform to `$HttpProvider`'s default transformer.

**Note:** Correct me if I'm wrong on this one but I believe this feature requires v1.1.2 or greater.

Comment: +1 for posting a solution that uses the newer `ngResource` features from the 1.1.x branch of AngularJS.

Comment: i'm going to try it!
i'm having some trouble with restangular not giving me the response on a post request, and it worked on ngresource.
reverting to the later would save me some time.

Comment: Cool. It is always good to limit the number of libraries you have to load. Also, here is an answer I posted recently that solved a similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332922/how-can-i-insert-commands-before-or-prevent-https-jsonp-automatic-parsing-in-a/17333030#17333030 @Shaman was looking for a way to transform the response before the default transform.

Comment: it works... I had to save the `meta` as a property on the `objects` array for later use.. 
I will now find a way to set this on all my resources (but not globally)

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try something like [restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular).

There is some configuration needed to make that work.  An example is [here](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#my-response-is-actually-wrapped-with-some-metadata-how-do-i-get-the-data-in-that-case).

Answer (score 3):

I ended up doing the following in order to preserve the `meta` object directly on the results returned by `Reminder.query()` (expanding on the answer from @moderndegree).

```
var Reminder = $resource('/api/v1/reminder/', {}, {
  query: {
    method: 'GET',
    isArray: true,
    transformResponse: $http.defaults.transformResponse.concat([
      function (data, headersGetter) {
          return data.objects;
      }
    ]),
    interceptor: {
      response: function(response) {
        response.resource.meta = response.data.meta;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

That allows you to get the `meta` value directly on the returned object:

```
var reminders = Reminder.query(...);
console.log(reminders.meta); // Returns `meta` as expected.
```

I think it would also be possible to do something similar inside the callback from `Reminder.query` since the `response` object is available there as well.