# How can I insert commands before or prevent $http's JSONP automatic parsing in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp

It seems like pretty much every question or explanation I find regarding $http or angularjs in general assumes you can modify the response from your requests. I can't do that and the response I'm getting is malformed (according to the AngularJS parser). It's malformed in a consistent way so I could modify the plain text to fix the problem before parsing it, but both response interceptors and transform response functions occur after the default (content type based?) parsing.

**Edit:** The issue is with the fact that I need to use the JSONP methodology to make a request for information from another site, but the data does not have the expected JSONP callback so something (I'm still not sure if its the browser based on the content or the AngularJS code) throws a syntax error.

New question: Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Until now, nobody has been able to answer the open question about parsing a JSONP response before processing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been tested and does work. Let me know if you have any further questions. http://jsfiddle.net/moderndegree/Kn3Tc/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        {{results.tada}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']).
factory('myService', function($http, $resource, $log){
    return $resource('/', {}, {
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            // placed custom transform ahead of $http default
            transformRequest: [function(data, headersGetter){
                $log.info(data);
                $log.info(headersGetter());
            }].concat($http.defaults.transformRequest),
            // placed custom transform ahead of $http default
            transformResponse: [function (data, headersGetter) {
                $log.info(data);
                $log.info(headersGetter());
                data = {tada:"Check your console"};
                return data;
            }].concat($http.defaults.transformResponse)
        }
    });
}).
controller('myController', function(myService, $scope) {
    $scope.results = myService.get();
});
```

**Update**
To use JSONP, just switch the method to JSONP. You can read more about ngResource [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

Comment: I haven't tried it with $resource, but in $http transformResponse occurs AFTER the automatic parsing. So if I have malformed JSON (or XML or whatever) it errors before it gets to the anonymous function and 'data' is undefined. Also, headersGetter is undefined no matter what I do. What version of Angular is this for?

Comment: also, `$esource` extends `$http` so I believe you might have the same issue.

Comment: It took me a little while but I figured out how to get it to work. In the jsFiddle example, I just load the root HTML in order to demonstrate a bad JSON response. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Pertinent detail I apparently missed - I need to access data on an external site so I'm using JSONP. The problem is, therefore, in the JSONP callback code (which requires the data to be parsed - sort of - to make the callback first). Do you know of any way around this?

Comment: Both of you accurately answered my original question but this is what helped me realize that what I want I'm trying to do just isn't possible due to overly aggressive 'security' restrictions.

Comment: + for use of concat to push to array. Was looking for how to do that.

Comment: @Shaman why is this the correct answer? I doesn't work with JSONP?

Comment: @Betty St, the initial question did not mention JSONP. I have since updated my answer.

Comment: @BettySt The answer does work with JSONP. It just didn't work for my use case for unrelated reasons. I was not concerned with the fact that the example used "GET" as the method because I didn't need code I could copy/paste. I needed to know how, and this answered that.

Comment: I guess there is no way to add a function before parsing

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the angular documentation says

> To globally augment or override the default transforms, modify the
>   $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest and
>   $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse properties. These properties
>   are by default an array of transform functions, which allows you to
>   push or unshift a new transformation function into the transformation
>   chain. You can also decide to completely override any default
>   transformations by assigning your transformation functions to these
>   properties directly without the array wrapper.

Basically what you would need to do is to configure the $httpProvider

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
//Define your transform function
//push your trasform function to the start of the array  $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse
//Or replace the transformResponse array with a function or a new array of tranform functions.

}]);
```

Now the trasform function that you implement should be first function in the array. Since there is already a string to JSON transform function there.

Comment: I've tried this already several different ways and it doesn't seem like it ever disables whatever code is throwing the parse error. I'm beginning to think it might be a version issue. I won't have access to my dev environment until tomorrow, so I'll update you then once I've had a chance to check the versions.

Comment: I checked the source code for angularjs and it pushes the default tranformResponse which does the string to json transformation. If the error is not due to conversion to JSON, then you would have to provide more details\

Comment: Pertinent detail I apparently missed - I need to access data on an external site so I'm using JSONP. The problem is, therefore, in the JSONP callback code (which requires the data to be parsed - sort of - to make the callback first). Do you know of any way around this?

Comment: I guess there is no way to add a function before parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has added $jsonpCallbacks in version 1.5.8
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/jsonpCallbacks.js

This allows you to modify the callback function.